# UFT/QTP - Extract Values From List Within WebEdit

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am attempting to capture all the list items in the WebList elements throughout the entire application, however, while below code works on the WebLists, it does not work on this WebEdit.

When you click on the WebEdit, a long list of values appear (similar to a WebList) and as you type for your value, the list becomes shorter. That is how the WebEdit was set up.

But now, how do I get the values in this list?

Here is the code I have for the WebLists:

***Code***

```
Set WebLink = Browser("browser").Page("page")

listval = WebLink.WebElement("xpath:= ((//*[contains(text(), 'Name')]))[1]/following::SELECT[1]").GetROProperty("all items")

listvalues = split(listval,";") 

For j = LBound(listvalues,1) To UBound(listvalues,1)

    'Print listvalues(j)
    writeToTextFile(listvalues(j))

Next

ExitTest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **it depends on the implementation.**

The long one:
There is no universal widget for comboboxes (Like there is for edit fields or lists / selects, radiobuttons etc) **=> there is no universal solution but only guidelines.**

You need to spy on those objects that appear in the combobox, see their XPath and / or other properties (the css classname they belong to, for example) and then execute a second query that selects all such items. Afterwards you have to extract the value of the selected elements; which might be as simple as getting the *innertext* Property or you may need to dig even deeper in the HTML hierarchies.

You would need to pay careful attention for synchronisation(Waiting until all search result elements appear), Filtering (using the XPath, Description Objects and ChildObjects method on your WebPage) and then extraction( getting the property /element that contains the actual value of that WebElement)

So again: These combobox solutions are not universal therefore without seeing their code the best what one can provide to you is universal guidelines which should work in most of the situations. (You would need some familiarity with Web Programming and the UFT Framework / Robot)